# optimizing over a set of symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to minimize a complicated loss function, $f\left(\Lambda\right)$ over a set of symmetric matrices, $S_{p}$ of dimension p, such that all the eigenvalues of $\Lambda \in \left[0,1\right]$. I want to set this up as univariate optimization problem. Using spectral decomposition, I can write $\Lambda=Q \Sigma Q^\top$. Where $\Sigma$ is p-dimensional diagonal matrix with eigenvalues along the diagonal. I have freedom to choose the orthogonal matrix Q. Are there any strategies/characterizations to select Q. What kind of restrictions can I impose on Q? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

I also know that, $$\lim_{k \to \infty }\left(\Lambda-I_p\right)^k = 0$$

Comment: the answer depends on your $f$. However, there is a Lagrange duality theory for $S_p$ like for $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I updated the description

Comment: It's not clear to me how you can be looking for a "univariate" optimization problem when your optimization variable is a symmetric matrix with $p(p+1)/2$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: I have p restrictions but I dont know how to choose the remaining $\frac{p\left(p-1\right)}{2}$ restrictions.

Comment: Trying to specify a matrix as orthogonal is usually a bad idea. Without more knowledge on $f$, you should apply nonlinear semi definite programming techniques. Also the limit just implies that all eigenvalues is in the open interval $(0,1)$.